# My client/server program created in vb6(winsock) dont work on WAN but perfectly works n LAN Why?

Tags: vb6, winsock

I've created a simple client/server program with the help of winsock in vb6. It perfectly works on LAN but the problem is it doesn't work on WAN. All ports are already open, Firewall is already Off, I have dynamic IP so I used [No-ip](http://no-ip.com) to get named IP address.
One more think I want to ask is , is it important to open port on both client and server? For eg- I've created the program on port 50505 and on the client computer the port is open but is it important to open 50505 on server also??

Here is my [project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/49564051/Winsock.zip).

If anyone could find the problem please let me know. I would appreciate a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first make sure that in the client side program that the Localport is not set to anything because Windows will assign it one, but the RemotePort is set to 50505.  On the server side, the RemotePort is set to nothing, and the LocalPort is set to 50505.

Next you need to make sure your server has a static IP on your network.
So if your router's LAN IP is 192.168.1.1 you need to set your server's to 
something like 192.168.1.50, just make sure that it doesn't get put in the range or the 
DHCP server (That's the server that gives each computer a IP address from the router).

Next you need to setup your router for "Port forwarding".  Be default your router had no idea what to do with data that the internet sends to it.  You have to setup the router to forward any data from port 50505 to your server on your network.

While this seams really long and drawn out, it shouldn't take more than 5-10 min's to setup.

Good luck!

Comment: lets just say it took me 2 years to understand what you said.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the router that the server is behind to forward connections on that port to the computer running the server.

Otherwise, the client will not be able to connect to the server.

Comment: That assumes he is behind a NAT router, an "unusual" (almost "abnormal") condition in Internet terms though all too common today and almost the rule for desktops.

Comment: ur answer didnt helped me. Please i want a solution

Comment: @Sam: What part don't you understand?

Comment: See, i opened ports on both computers(which are on WAN) i.e 50505 and i disabled firewall on both computers. I tried connecting but failed. Why is this happening. It works perfect on LAN. my router has a option of NAT in which there is an option of virtual ports which helps to open ports and i successfully opened it, still i failed hard. It looks like winsock is only for LAN but i know m wrong. PLEASE FIND ANY SOLUTION, PLEASE