# winsock connect function is working only on high speed connection

Tags: vba, vb6, connection, winsock

I'm using `winsock` in my VB6 application, this is my code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()  

  With Winsock1  
    .Close  
    .RemoteHost = Hostip
    .RemotePort = port number
    .Connect
  End With
End Sub
```

My problem is when I'm using a high speed connection (4G) the connection works fine but using other connections like (3G,wise...) it returns the following message:

> the attempt to connect timed out

How do I remedy this?

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326441/my-client-server-program-created-in-vb6winsock-dont-work-on-wan-but-perfectly?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to set a longer connection timeout. There is no way to do this directly with the control. Below is a modified sample from a retired KB article. The orignal code does not include the SO_SNDTIMEO, or SO_RCVTIMEO options.

```
Option Explicit

' Error returned by Winsock API.
Const SOCKET_ERROR = -1

' Level number for (get/set)sockopt() to apply to socket itself.
Const SOL_SOCKET = 65535      ' Options for socket level.
Const IPPROTO_TCP = 6         ' Protocol constant for TCP.

' option flags per socket
Const SO_DEBUG = &H1&         ' Turn on debugging info recording
Const SO_ACCEPTCONN = &H2&    ' Socket has had listen() - READ-ONLY.
Const SO_REUSEADDR = &H4&     ' Allow local address reuse.
Const SO_KEEPALIVE = &H8&     ' Keep connections alive.
Const SO_DONTROUTE = &H10&    ' Just use interface addresses.
Const SO_BROADCAST = &H20&    ' Permit sending of broadcast msgs.
Const SO_USELOOPBACK = &H40&  ' Bypass hardware when possible.
Const SO_LINGER = &H80&       ' Linger on close if data present.
Const SO_OOBINLINE = &H100&   ' Leave received OOB data in line.

Const SO_DONTLINGER = Not SO_LINGER
Const SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE = Not SO_REUSEADDR ' Disallow local address reuse.

' Additional options.
Const SO_SNDBUF = &H1001&     ' Send buffer size.
Const SO_RCVBUF = &H1002&     ' Receive buffer size.
Const SO_ERROR = &H1007&      ' Get error status and clear.
Const SO_TYPE = &H1008&       ' Get socket type - READ-ONLY.

' TCP Options
Const TCP_NODELAY = &H1&      ' Turn off Nagel Algorithm.

' linger structure
Private Type LINGER_STRUCT
  l_onoff As Integer          ' Is linger on or off?
  l_linger As Integer         ' Linger timeout in seconds.
End Type

'timeout structure
Private Type TIMEOUT_STRUCT
    tv_sec As Long  'seconds
    tv_usec As Long 'milliseconds
End Type

'Timeout options
Const SO_SNDTIMEO = &H1005& 'send timeout
Const SO_RCVTIMEO = &H1006& 'receive timeout

' Winsock API declares
Private Declare Function setsockopt Lib "wsock32.dll" (ByVal s As Long, ByVal level As Long, ByVal optname As Long, optval As Any, ByVal optlen As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function getsockopt Lib "wsock32.dll" (ByVal s As Long, ByVal level As Long, ByVal optname As Long, optval As Any, optlen As Long) As Long

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  ' Read all the options and present in a message box.
  Dim socket As Long

  socket = Winsock1.SocketHandle

  If socket = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Socket"
  Else
    MsgBox "Socket Options:" & vbCrLf & _
           "    SO_DEBUG: " & CStr(GetSocketOption(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_DEBUG)) & vbCrLf & _
           "    SO_ACCEPTCONN: " & CStr(GetSocketOption(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ACCEPTCONN)) & vbCrLf & _
           "    SO_REUSEADDR: " & CStr(GetSocketOption(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR)) & vbCrLf & _
           "    SO_KEEPALIVE: " & CStr(GetSocketOption(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE)) & vbCrLf & _
           "    SO_DONTROUTE: " & CStr(GetSocketOption(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_DONTROUTE)) & vbCrLf & _
           "    SO_BROADCAST: " & CStr(GetSocketOption(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST)) & vbCrLf & _
           "    SO_USELOOPBACK: " & CStr(GetSocketOption(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_USELOOPBACK)) & vbCrLf & _
           "    SO_LINGER: " & CStr(GetSocketOption(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER)) & vbCrLf & _
           "    SO_OOBINLINE: " & CStr(GetSocketOption(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_OOBINLINE)) & vbCrLf & _
           "    SO_DONTLINGER: " & CStr(GetSocketOption(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_DONTLINGER)) & vbCrLf & _
           "    SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE: " & CStr(GetSocketOption(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE)) & vbCrLf & _
           "    SO_SNDBUF: " & CStr(GetSocketOption(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF)) & vbCrLf & _
           "    SO_RCVBUF: " & CStr(GetSocketOption(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF)) & vbCrLf & _
           "    SO_ERROR: " & CStr(GetSocketOption(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR)) & vbCrLf & _
           "    SO_TYPE: " & CStr(GetSocketOption(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE)) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "TCP Options:" & vbCrLf & _
           "    TCP_NODELAY: " & CStr(GetSocketOption(socket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY))
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
  Dim lResult As Long     ' Results of 1st option.
  Dim tout As TIMEOUT_STRUCT

  If (Winsock1.Protocol = sckTCPProtocol) Then
    tout.tv_sec = 10
    tout.tv_usec = 0

    lResult = setsockopt(Winsock1.SocketHandle, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, tout, LenB(tout))

    If (lResult = SOCKET_ERROR) Then
      MsgBox "Error setting SO_SNDTIMEO option: " & Translate_DLL_Error(Err.LastDllError)
    Else
      MsgBox "SO_SNDTIMEO option set."
    End If

  End If

End Sub

Public Function GetSocketOption(lSocket As Long, lLevel As Long, lOption As Long) As Long
  Dim lResult As Long       ' Result of API call.
  Dim lBuffer As Long       ' Buffer to get value into.
  Dim lBufferLen As Long    ' len of buffer.
  Dim linger As LINGER_STRUCT

  ' Linger requires a structure so we will get that option differently.
  If (lOption <> SO_LINGER) And (lOption <> SO_DONTLINGER) Then
    lBufferLen = LenB(lBuffer)
    lResult = getsockopt(lSocket, lLevel, lOption, lBuffer, lBufferLen)
  Else
    lBufferLen = LenB(linger)
    lResult = getsockopt(lSocket, lLevel, lOption, linger, lBufferLen)
    lBuffer = linger.l_onoff
  End If

  If (lResult = SOCKET_ERROR) Then
    GetSocketOption = Err.LastDllError
  Else
    GetSocketOption = lBuffer
  End If
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Winsock1.Bind 8377      ' Set up socket enough to get nonzero socket. handle
End Sub
```

You can find the original article at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/237688

Comment: hi thanks for your reply,i didnt see anything regardling port number and remotehost and to connect

Comment: @Nicole, correct. I assumed you knew how to do that already. The sample above shows how to set and read the winsock options. You specifically want to set the SO_SNDTIMEO option as shown in the `Command2_Click` event. After setting the timeout you can proceed with the rest of your code. Note though that the winsock control must be in a bind state (the SocketHandle > 0) to set the options. In the sample this is down in the Form_Load event. More details about how to use the Winsock control can be found at, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733709(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Hi again, ok i understand the code but still request time out,the question is  should i use 8377 to bind?and i should connect after setoption or before?

Comment: this given code should be used on the client side or server side?

Comment: @Nicole, The 8377 is the local port to bind to. Replace it with your port. The send timeout is used on the side with the Winsock control that is getting the timeout error.